# ASP.Net button won't render background-image

Tags: asp.net, css, url, background-image, html-input

I've checked most of the linked questions here on this topic and also in asp.net forums and I am stuck. I have the following in one of my .aspx pages:

```
<asp:button ID="btnAdmin" runat="server" Width="70px" Height="30px"
     Text="Admin" 
     ToolTip="Facilities for administrators" 
     CssClass="buttonStyleAdmin">
</asp:button>
```

I have the following in my .css file:

```
.buttonStyleAdmin
{
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url('imgBlue-button-base.png');
font-size: 1.0em;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

I understand the url syntax should be relative to the location of the CSS file. After some trials with the url pointing to the images directory of the web, I gave up and copied the above .png file to the root of the web; that is, it is adjacent to the .css file itself.

I have used both Google developer tools and Firebug in Firefox and the matched CSS rules seem to be correct. That is, I can hover over the section of the tool and the URL resolves such that the image itself is displayed.
[image: GoogleChromeDeveloperTool-view]

Here is the Firebug view of the rendered page:
[image]

If I can get this to resolve with both the .png file and the .css file in the root of the website, then I'd like to change the reference to the images folder where all the other images are gathered but with this failing with both files in the root of the web, I clearly need some advice on what could be wrong.
I am using Visual Studio 2008 on a webserver running .Net Framework 3.5 (Windows Server 2003).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
display: block;
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

into .buttonStyleAdmin.

I placed your code/css into a blank project and it worked just fine with a place holder image.

Failing that, if you have adblock try turning that off. Apologies if you have tried the above but you did not state what you have tried already from other cases / ASP forums.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried it and no real change (other than the relocation of the button itself). The image is still not rendered as the background of the <input type=submit..> control. I've never heard of adblock but after searching, I don't think I have it. If it is a Chrome extension, I don't have it. Same with Firefox. In short, I don't think I have adblock. Thanks for your interest. Any other ideas. From what I showed you, I take it you think it should work, correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell it should, I took your exact code and put it into VS and it worked fine. Would an Image Button work for you?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008 and hence CSS 2.0 as far as I can tell. Is your VS the same?

Comment: I used VS2010 on a .net 3.5 project. Have you tried using one of these instead http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_imagebutton.asp ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up that works:

```
<asp:button id="btnAdmin" runat="server" 
    Text="Admin"
    ToolTip="Facilities for administrators"
    CssClass="coolbutton">
</asp:button>
```

And the CSS:

```
.coolbutton
{
-moz-border-radius: 1em;
-webkit-border-radius: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
background-image: url(images/imgBlue-button-base.jpg);
background-position: center;
color: White; 
cursor:pointer;
}
.coolbutton:hover 
{
-moz-border-radius: 1em;
-webkit-border-radius: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
background-image: url(images/imgBlue-button-baseOn.jpg);
background-position: center;
color: Black; 
cursor:pointer;
}
```